# How to scroll tab control with scroll wheel as soon as i select the tab in C#

Tags: c#

In my application there are many combo box controls. I want to scroll horizontally to access all combo boxes. But the problem is when I select a particular tab page in tab control, it can't scroll through using the mouse wheel, but after I select something inside that tab control it allows me to scroll using the wheel.

Can someone give me a solution for this with detailed explanation where should I put the code parts?

Thanks!

```
{
    private IContainer components;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
     // tabControl2.Click += (s, e) => tabControl2.Focus();

    }


    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }
```

Comment: WPF, Winforms?  What tab control are you using?

Comment: need some more helps? if my solution works please mark it as answer :)

Comment: I'm using windows forms built in visual studio 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you do this under winforms.

This is because the Tab control is considered as a container, and thus won't get the focus unless explicitly doing so.

Try this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    // register the event handler here
    tabPage.Click += (s, e) => tabPage.Focus(); // this line can be omitted
    tabPage.MouseEnter += (s, e) => tabPage.Focus();
}
```

Above is the code that works for only one tab, if you want it applies to all tabs in your tab control, simply subscribe `MouseEnter` event for all tab pages using foreach:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    foreach (TabPage tabPage in TabControl.TabPages)
    {
        tabPage.MouseEnter += (s, e) => tabPage.Focus();
    }
}
```

If you have some dynamically created tab pages, subscribe `MouseEnter` event for them as well :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i tried this method ans sadly it's not working. still want to  click the button inside the tab control to scroll the tab

Comment: i edited my original question with code that i used, in my application there is no border

Comment: it's should be **tabPage** not **tabControl** that should get the Focus() fired.

Comment: sorry i correct that code but problem is still exist  :(

Comment: oh i guess you are clicking on non-client area of tab page (those tab headers are considered as non-client area, which don't allow you to capture click easily). I edited the code a bit, it's a bit hack-ish but should work though :P

Comment: wow thank you so much it worked  :) i don't know how to thank you i .. thank you very much and i have a one more question. can you please kind enough to show me how to add this to another tab page in the same form ? because it is useful to me there is another tab that want to scroll to see the content

Comment: post edited, please have a look :) if you have further questions fell free to contact me at nevets.st@gmail.com :)